# How to override existing object with dynamic values using spread/Object.assign

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object in my state. Then I'm adding values dynamically and it can look something like this:

```
{
  2311: 2
}
```

How can I override that `2311` value if it already exists without mutating the state.

Adding a new value is simple. I have an object `obj = { prop: val}` and then `{ ...this.state.obj, obj }`
but I can't remember how can I change the `obj` value that is dynamic.

I know that I can do deep copy using lodash or something, change that specific value and I' done but I want to know how to do that the way I described above.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Using Object.assign(obj1, obj2)

```
Object.assign(obj, { 2311: 'new value' })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do, for example:

```js
let obj = {test: 23, test2: 24, 2311: 2};
obj = {...obj, 2311: "new value"}
console.log(obj);
```

in this way, you will have all the previous values, and change just `2311` value

What i did here (`obj = {...obj, 2311: "new value"}`) it's copy all values from object and change just what i want, since in a object can't have two values with same key, the key `2311` is override with the new value